# Sending Mail using PHP on IIS 7 - Windows 2008 Server

Tags: php, windows, iis, email, windows-server-2008

I'm having trouble sending mail using PHP `mail()` on IIS 7 using Windows 2008 Server.
The server is dedicated, thus I have full control over my machine.
php.ini looks fine - ([mail function] is configured)
I don't get any error from `mail()` (with the right parameters of course)

btw - I got ASP and ASP.NET sending mails without any problems.

Would be very gratefully for help

Regards,
Roman

Comment: It seems that mail() returns false - thus failing the sending function.

Comment: Just a dumb question to cover all bases...is your mail service turned on?

Comment: sure :) it works great using ASP and .NET

Comment: I have enabled all email server and when i send email using telnet in IIS7 it works fine. But email doesnot go with the PHP code simple mail function

Answer (score 0):

I use http://pear.php.net/package/Mail.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the similar issues

I have tried sending email thru telnet from IIS server
Now I am having problem that i couldnt send email even with simple PHP function - mail();

The php code that i use is
`<?php mail("mail@rajanmaharjan.com.np", "hi", "test on today");?>` doesnot send email to mail@rajanmaharjan.com.np

I have already read lots of forums regading SMTP setup in IIS and others